# random function with a same probability for each value in R

Tags: r, algorithm, function, random, probability

is there any built in function in R, which I could use to generate a random value between the value I choose for with the same probability 
for example I have a vector which I want to assign 1 or 0 with 50% probability to each value.
is there any function which I could say what are my values and according to that the probabilities in other words: values(A,B,C,F), with a 0.25 probability for each and then assign that random value to each vector value.
thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick google search found this: http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/02/how-to-choose-a-random-number-in-r.html

```
random_value <- sample(values, 1)
```